# Return max value for dynamic rolling from pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 'A' column and i am looking for following result in max column .I have used loops but it's time consuming.I want to use lambda function so that after passing array of values ,i will get corresponding max value for each dynamic rolling .

```
   A                Max          
  100       
 100.87           100.87

99.800778         100.87

101.1281283     101.1281283

106.4575807     106.4575807

109.3212896     109.3212896

107.7907916     109.3212896

105.128359      109.3212896

103.8668187     109.3212896

108.9978396     109.3212896

110.0006197     110.0006197

106.9426025     110.0006197

108.6750726     110.0006197

101.1547576     110.0006197

102.7530028     110.0006197

97.68727973     110.0006197
```

Can someone help me find the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cummax():

```
df.A.cummax()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @user380090 No worries. If you find it helpful, please upvote and accept it as your answer.

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks!